# ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_partial_dependence' from 'sklearn.inspection'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am running sckitlearn 1.3 with the following code and get the following error:

```
print(__doc__)

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_partial_dependence' from 'sklearn.inspection' (C:\Users\thomp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection_*init*_.py)

How can I get this package loaded.

This error is returned

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_partial_dependence' from 'sklearn.inspection' (C:\Users\thomp\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\inspection_*init*_.py)

Comment: That should not give you errors.Have you tried checking your installation of scilit-learn? Maybe the installation is faulty. I would try removing scikit-learn and re-installing, to check if that solves your issues.

Comment: I reinstalled Anaconda so I am pretty sure my underlying scikitlearn is up to date.   thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot_partial_dependence` no longer exists in the [`inspection` module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.inspection) of scikit-learn version 1.3

To use `plot_partial_dependence`, one has to revert to scikit-learn version 0.24. See the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/partial_dependence.html#partial-dependence).

However, it seems that the current way to plot partial dependence is through [`PartialDependenceDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.PartialDependenceDisplay). One can read the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/partial_dependence.html#partial-dependence-plots) for more information.